# Stucked in d): $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ( \sum_{l=0}^{k} \frac{1}{l!} ) x^k $. Show $(1-x)g(x)=exp(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

For $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k $ We define the radius of convergence:

$ R $ :=  sup { $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ | ($a_k$ $\cdot$ $x^k$)   bounded sequence }

I have to find the radius of convergence for:

a)  $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k $

b) $  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k} $

c) $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ( \sum_{l=0}^{k} \frac{1}{l!} ) x^k $

d) Define $ g(x) := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ( \sum_{l=0}^{k} \frac{1}{l!} ) x^k $. Show that $ exp(x) = (1-x)g(x) $.

Remark: It is not allowed to use the Ratio test.

Attempt:

a) I think I solved this one. Use definition of radius of convergence. $ R $ = sup{ $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ |$ x^k$ bounded sequence } . Consider $x > 1 $ : Define $\alpha := x -1$.

$ x^k = (1+ \alpha)^k \ge 1 + k \cdot \alpha. $ (unbounded)

Consider now $ -1 < x < 1 $ : $ x^k $ is a null sequence ( bounded ) So $R = (-1,1)$. [ for $ x = 1, x= -1 $ the series is divergent ]

b) got this.$ R$ = sup { $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ | $\frac{x^k}{k}$ bounded sequence }. For $ x > 1 $ :

$\frac{x^k}{k}$  = $\frac{(1+\alpha)^k}{k}$ $\ge$ $\frac{1+k\alpha+\binom{k}{2}\alpha^2}{k}$ $\ge$ $\frac{k-1}{2}\alpha$  ( unbounded )

Consider $ x < 1 $ : $| \frac{x^k}{k} | \le \frac{1}{k} \le 1$ ( bounded ) So $ R  = [-1,1) $ [ for $ x = -1 $ the series is convergent ]

c) Here is my problem: So R = sup { $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ | $( \sum_{l=0}^{k} \frac{1}{l!} ) x^k$ bounded sequence }. Now I'm stucked. **Edit** : I think c) is done. So I'm only stucked in d).

d) First of all we can replace $g(x)$ with $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ( \sum_{l=0}^{k} \frac{1}{l!} ) x^k $. We get $ exp(x) = (1-x) ( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ( \sum_{l=0}^{k} \frac{1}{l!} ) x^k ) $. But what can I do now?

I hope you can help me.

Comment: $1,1$ and $1$ by locating the closest singularity to the origin.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{l=0}^k \frac 1{l!}$ is positive $\nearrow$ and converge so you can squeeze it between two constants (approx $e$).

Comment: $ | \sum\limits_{l=0}^k \frac 1{l!} x^k | \le e |x| ^k $ (bounded for $ |x|<1 $.) And $ | \sum\limits_{l=0}^k \frac 1{l!} x^k |  \ge |x|^k $  ( unbounded for $ |x|>1 $) Is this ok so far?

Comment: Part d) is just using Cauchy's product for two series $\exp(x) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{k} /k! $ and $1/(1-x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k}$.